# Python Google spreadsheets v4 API

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

When I try to add a line in google spreadsheets in python via google API that starts with `=GOOGLEFINANCE(A2)` i get the following in my spreadsheet '=GOOGLEFINANCE(A2) with the function obviously not working.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Please show us a small code that produces the error.

Comment: Have you tried using 
valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED' in your query?